# Google Search Result Issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, search, seo, google-search-console

I have site example.com.I have one page "Page 1" on that site.I added "Page 1" page link in "Home Page".i search "Page 1" on **google search** it display "example.com" first instead off "Page 1" page in search result

Google Search not work Proper in My case

Comment: Off topic, please use [Webmaster SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) for questions regarding SEO. It would be good if you included more details, I don't think the question is answerable as you posted it.

Comment: i have added all detail in above question there are no more deatail for above question

Comment: Please, provide more details, as Amadan said. Give us the exact url, and link to specific page, so we can help better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give Google some time to find about Page 1 and to index it properly.

If the issue persists after a couple of days or a week, you may try to [implement a better title tag](https://ligatures.net/content/expertise/meta-title-and-description.html)  (see personal post) and `<h1>` header in your page to emphasize what is distinctive about Page 1. This may solve the issue, but keep in mind Google is the ultimate decision maker.